# Python dictionary pointwise output

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, nested-loops, dictionary-comprehension

if i have a dictionary:

```
d={
's':['a','b','c'], 
'v':['d','e'], 
'r':['g','h','i'],}
```

(which could have an arbitrary number of keys)

how can i output a list of all the pair-wise combinations i.e.

```
['adg','adh', 'adi', 'aeg', 'aeh', 'aei', 'bdg', 'bdh', 'bdi', 'beg', 'beh', 'bei', 'cdg', 'cdh', 'cdi', 'ceg', 'ceh', 'cei']
```

i used:

```
l=list()
temp=''
for i in range(len(d['s'])):
    for j in range(len(d['v'])):
        for k in range(len(d['r'])):
            temp=d['s'][i]+d['v'][j]+d['r'][k]
            print(temp)
            l.append(temp)
```

but i need to make it generic for an arbitray number of keys.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and `str.join` in a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import product

out = [''.join(p) for p in product(*d.values())]
```

output:

```
['adg', 'adh', 'adi', 'aeg', 'aeh', 'aei',
 'bdg', 'bdh', 'bdi', 'beg', 'beh', 'bei',
 'cdg', 'cdh', 'cdi', 'ceg', 'ceh', 'cei']
```